# Machine learning for betting (how to optimize overall profit)

Tags: machine-learning, python

How to use machine learning in betting (optimize for overall profit)?

Suppose I have two sports: football and basketball.
My task is to **maximize overall profit**. What approach can be used for such a task?

In fact, I have information about 50 000 bets.

Simplified demo data (for example I stake 1\$ on odds 2 and I win, I receive  stake * (win - bet) == 1\$. If I lose, I win `-1` (just lose my stake)):

```
sport odds won$
football 2 1
football 2 1
football 2 1
football 2 1
football 2 -1
football 2 -1
basketball 6 5
basketball 6 5
basketball 2 -1
basketball 2 -1
basketball 2 -1
basketball 2 -1
```

Betting on football gives me 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 - 1 -1 == 2\$. I win 4/6 games (high precision), but I win only 2\$.

Betting on basketball gives me 5 + 5 - 1 - 1 - 1 -1 == 6\$. I win only 2/6 games (low precision), but I win 6\$.

As I understand, using typical classification approaches (LogisticRegression, RandomForestClassifier, XGBoost) are optimized on precision. But that is not what I want (I can guess win-lose good, but still win a little).

To maximize overall profit I should bet on basketball.

What is the correct approach for such tasks?

**My base approach:**

I've started just with classification, made two classes: 1 for Win and 0 for Lose, and trained the model for guessing Win/Lose. My model can predict the probability of class 1 (win probability) that is `my_probability`. Odd in betting is `1/probability`, so I have `bookmaker_probability`. Having that two probabilities, I can use value `confidence == my_probability/bookmaker_probability`.
In theory the higher confidence, the higher probability that I'll gain extra money. So betting not on all bets, but on top 50% bets sorted by confidence I should receive much better results. In fact, such an approach gives me a little higher ROI, 0-3% higher than the base ROI.

**What is the correct approach?**

Is it possible to use classical classification algorithms (like LogisticRegression, RandomForestClassifier, XGBoost, etc) to optimize not precision but something like "win function" by default?

(If this is important, I use Python)

Any keyword or suggestion to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. This is an optimization problem, and apparently one which can be easily be solved deterministically: In the example that you described, you found the answer (best game to invest in is basketball) using a deterministic calculation of the expected value for each game. If the answer can be found deterministically, there's no point using ML. If you train a classifier with this kind of data, it should be to predict the *outcome* of a bet, not the overall probability (and it would need indicators of the outcome as features).

Comment: Also it's incorrect to say that classification is optimized on precision.